# Can I use Weinstein–Aronszajn identity to show that the eigenvalues of AB and BA are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the matrices $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times m}$ and $B\in \mathbb{K}^{m \times n}$ .

Can I use the Weinstein–Aronszajn identity to show that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues? If so, how would I accomplish this? If not, what would be a good way to show my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can use Weinstein-Aronszajn identity $\det (I_n - AB) = \det (I_m - BA)$ to show that non-zero eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ coincide.

---

**Proof** Let $\lambda$ be a non-zero eigenvalue of $AB$. This means that $\det (\lambda I_n - AB) = 0$, however

$$
\begin{align}
\det (\lambda I_n - AB) &= \lambda^n\det\left(I_n - \left(\frac{1}{\lambda}A\right)B\right) \\
&= \lambda^n\det\left(I_m - B\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}A\right)\right) \\
&= \lambda^{n-m}\det\left(\lambda I_m - BA\right)
\end{align}
$$

and we see that $\det (\lambda I_m - BA) = 0$ which means that $\lambda$ is a non-zero eigenvalue of $BA$. The converse follows by the analogous argument.